# Contra indicações em IIFE's

Tags: javascript, angularjs, objetos

Existe alguma contra indicação utilizar IIFE's dentro do contexto de um objeto?

Por exemplo, nas propriedades `begin` e `created` eu faço a função se auto executar para definir as propriedades no momento da instanciação da variável.

Exemplo:

```
var example = {
                example_id: scope.id,
                //Formating date to US
                begin: (function () {
                    var dateBr = scope.begin;
                    var dateUs = dateBr.split('/').reverse();
                    return dateUs.join('-');
                }()),
                period: scope.period,
                created: (function () {
                    var d = new Date();
                    var curr_day = d.getDate();
                    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
                    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
                    var curr_hour = d.getHours();
                    var curr_min = d.getMinutes();
                    var curr_sec = d.getSeconds();
                    return curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_day + " " + curr_hour + ":" + curr_min + ":" + curr_sec;
                }())
            };
```

Gostaria de saber se utilizar as IIFE's assim pode trazer algum problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não, não vejo nenhum problema em fazer isso. Pelo contrário, há vantagens, já que você não está vazando variáveis para o escopo global.

Comment: Obrigado Amigo, já confirmo a resposta de cara, porque já te conheço a um bom tempo aqui do SO e não é a primeira vez que me ajuda. Abração.

Comment: De nada. Eu posso estar errado também, mas realmente nunca vi nenhuma contra-indicação a essa prática.